# Best method to insert master-detail records using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Am new to Asp.net and EF.Sorry to consider this question.
I would like to know what is the best way to design a master-detail web form in asp.net. Of-course the master fields will be simple controls, but am worried about the detail records which can be around 50-60 records.
Should I use a grid view and every time add a new row for a new records.
or
I should use controls in a line like columns and then add all controls for a new row.
or is there any other way to achieve this.

Am using EF for insert ,update,delete.

Please suggest a way if possible with an example.

Comment: There is nothing to worry about when you're insert 50-60 records. By using AddRange you can insert thousands records. Normally, when somebody ask question, he must provide his own code and explain what result is expecting.

Comment: andrey.shedko : So I should follow grid view method. I'll be careful with code part next time.